# How do I minimize a dynamically allocated string array in C?

Tags: c, dynamic-memory-allocation, address-sanitizer

How do I reduce the size of a dynamically allocated string array?

```
int main(){
    char **a = malloc(sizeof(char *)*5);
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        a[i] = malloc(sizeof(char) * 10);
    }
    strcpy(a[0], "apple");
    strcpy(a[1], "cat");
    strcpy(a[2], "dog");
    strcpy(a[3], "sun");
    strcpy(a[4], "moon");
    //Now I want to get rid of dog and resize the array to 5
}
```

I tried creating new dynamic string array like so:

```
char **temp_storage = malloc(sizeof(char *) * 4);
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
    temp_storage[i] = malloc(sizeof(char) * 10);
}
```

Then copying all the element from 'a' to 'temp_storage' except 'dog'.
After everything is completed, I free all the element in 'a'

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    free(a[i]);
    a[i] = NULL;
}
```

Then I realloc a to size of 4. And copying all the element in 'temp_storage' to 'a'.

But I keep getting AddressSanitizer Error.

Comment: Show the AddressSanitizer errors and show the copy and realloc code.  That is, provide a [minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: If you truly want to size-optimize, you would call strlen on each string and then malloc + memcpy after that. In practice though, these kind of optimizations are unlikely to be meaningful. If anything, you should focus on writing fast and readable code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't really need another temporary array if you just want to delete one entry. All you have to do is:

1. Find the entry you want to delete (you may already have the index or you may want to search for the content).
2. Free that entry.
3. Move all other entries back one position (or just move the last one in place of the one that was deleted, if you don't care about order this is way faster).
4. Reallocate with `realloc()` to resize the array.

Here's an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define ENTRY_SIZE 10

int main(void) {
    size_t size = 5;
    char **arr, **tmp;
    size_t i;

    arr = malloc(sizeof(char *) * size);
    if (arr == NULL) {
        perror("malloc failed");
        return 1;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        arr[i] = malloc(sizeof(char) * ENTRY_SIZE);
        if (arr[i] == NULL) {
            perror("malloc failed");
            return 1;
        }
    }

    strcpy(arr[0], "apple");
    strcpy(arr[1], "cat");
    strcpy(arr[2], "dog");
    strcpy(arr[3], "sun");
    strcpy(arr[4], "moon");

    // Search for "dog" and remove it if found
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (!strcmp(arr[i], "dog")) {
            free(arr[i]);
            break;
        }
    }

    // If "dog" was found and removed
    if (i < size) {
        // Move all elements after "dog" back one position
        for (; i < size - 1; i++)
            arr[i] = arr[i + 1];

        // Resize the array
        size--;
        tmp = realloc(arr, sizeof(char *) * size);
        if (tmp == NULL) {
            perror("realloc failed");
            return 1;
        }

        arr = tmp;
    }

    // Print everything to show the results
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
        printf("%d: %s\n", i, arr[i]);

    // Free everything
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
        free(arr[i]);
    free(arr);

    return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
0: apple
1: cat
2: sun
3: moon
```

If you do not care about the order of the elements, you don't need to move all of them, just move the last one in place of the deleted one:

```
    if (i < size) {
        arr[i] = arr[size - 1];

        size--;
        tmp = realloc(arr, sizeof(char *) * size);

        // Same as above...
    }
```

Result:

```
0: apple
1: cat
2: moon
3: sun
```